# Scala equivalent of python itertools 'cycle'

Tags: python, scala, functional-programming, generator, python-itertools

Is there an equivalent of python's itertools.cycle()?

I would like to take a list of arrays and endlessly cycle them. So, if the arrays are named A through D, itertools.cycle can do:

```
itertools.cycle('[A,B,C,D]') --> A B C D A B C D...
```

This 'cycles' or 'rolls' the original collection.

I am digging into Scala streams in order to answer this question, but I thought I would ask to see if I am missing some built-in functionality.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `Stream.continually(...).flatten`.

Comment: `Iterator.continually(...).flatMap(x => x) ` will also do the trick

Comment: Great responses, thanks! Am giving both methods a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Iterator.continually** will do the trick

```
 Iterator.continually("scala").flatMap(x => x)
```

or

```
Iterator.continually("scala": Seq[Char]).flatten
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> Iterator.continually("scala").flatMap(x => x).take(100).foreach(println)

scala> Iterator.continually("scala": Seq[Char]).flatten.take(100).foreach(println)
```

Or

Yes you can use Stream to model this

```
def cycle(str: String): Stream[String] = str #:: cycle(str)
```

usage:

```
cycle("scala").flatten
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> def cycle(str: String): Stream[String] = str #:: cycle(str)
cycle: (str: String)Stream[String]

scala> cycle("java").take(100)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[String] = Stream(java, ?)

scala> cycle("java").take(100).force
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[String] = Stream(java, java, java, java, java, java, ... )
```

Comment: `flatmap{x=>x)` is `flatten`

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul `scala>  Iterator.continually("scala").flatten
<console>:12: error: value flatten is not a member of Iterator[String]
        Iterator.continually("scala").flatten`
                                      ^

Comment: Just spotted that too. That's an odd omission. Especially as `Stream` **does** have `flatten`

Comment: `flatten' is provided as an extension method for nested collections (see `TraversableOnce.FlattenOps` in the standard library source code). In order to make it available for strings you have to give a hint to the Scala compiler that you want to treat it as a sequence of characters: `Iterator.continually("scala": Seq[Char]).flatten.take(10).foreach(println)`

Comment: @stefanobaghino let me check

Answer (score 4):

Here I used a combination of the `continually` method of the `Stream` object and then flattened the result, hope this helps:

```
scala> Stream.continually(array).flatten
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> val array = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
array: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> val stream = Stream.continually(array).flatten
stream: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> stream.take(10).foreach(println)
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
1
2
```